# UWP DataGridComboBoxColumn change row values when selection changes

Tags: uwp, telerik, uwp-xaml, telerik-grid

I'm working on a project where I need to select a value from a list of objects and then update the other values displayed in the same row based on the selection that is made, with the properties of the selected object. I bind the list in my VM (using Prism) to the DataGridComboBoxColumn and is working fine, but there's no event SelectionChanged that I can bind to. I'm actually using Telerik's RadDataGrid, my code is:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="ArticlesDataGrid" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                 ItemsSource="{x:Bind MasterMenuItem.Articles, Mode=TwoWay}" UserEditMode="Inline" UserGroupMode="Disabled" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridComboBoxColumn PropertyName="Code" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Articles}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="Code" />
            <telerikGrid:DataGridComboBoxColumn PropertyName="Description" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Articles}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Description" />
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="MeasureUnit.Description" CanUserEdit="False" />
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="VatCode.Description" CanUserEdit="False"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Price" CanUserEdit="False"/>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Quantity" />
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Total" CanUserEdit="False" />
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

I need that when the columns Description or Code are changed, I can update the content in the others columns of the same row. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling an event, you could implement your logic in the setters of the `Description` and `Code` properties, e.g.:

```
private string _description;
public string Description
{
    get { return _description; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _description, value);
        //your "selection changed" logic goes here...
    }
}
```

As @Xavier Xie suggests, the class where the `Description`, `Code`, `Price`, `Quantity`, etc. properties are defined should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications for the view to be refreshed automatically. Please refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) for more information about this.

Since you are using Prism, you could inherit from `Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase` and call the `SetProperty<T>` method to both set and raise a change notification for a property.

Answer (score 1):

You did not need SelectionChanged event. You just need to make your model class implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged), when the value of DataGridComboBoxColumn changed, the model object's property value also would be changed. Then, you could change other properties' value in it.

Since you have not provide your code-behind code, so I just make a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="ArticlesDataGrid" Margin="0,8,0,0"
                             ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel}" UserEditMode="Inline" UserGroupMode="Disabled" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
            <telerikGrid:DataGridComboBoxColumn PropertyName="Option" ItemsSourcePath="Options" />
            <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Total" CanUserEdit="False" />
        </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
```

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _Total;
    public int Total
    {
        get { return _Total; }
        set
        {
            if (_Total != value)
            {
                _Total = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Option;
    public string Option
    {
        get { return _Option; }
        set
        {
            if (_Option != value)
            {
                _Option = value;
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "option1":this.Total = 1;break;
                    case "option2": this.Total = 2;break;
                    default: this.Total = 0;break;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("Option");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Options { get; set;}
}
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        ViewModel.Add(new Test() {Total=0,Options=new ObservableCollection<string>() {"--","option1","option2" } });
        ViewModel.Add(new Test() { Total = 0, Options = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"--" ,"option1", "option2" } });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Test> ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```